# Count number of lines in a txt file with Python excluding blank lines

Tags: python

I wish to count the number of lines in a .txt file which looks something like this:

```
apple
orange
pear

hippo
donkey
```

Where there are blank lines used to separate blocks. The result I'm looking for, based on the above sample, is five (lines).

How can I achieve this?

As a bonus, it would be nice to know how many blocks/paragraphs there are. So, based on the above example, that would be two blocks.

Comment: Does it need to be python? `grep . filename | wc -l` will give you the  lines easily.

Comment: @Daenyth It's part of a larger Python script, so ideally yes.

Comment: @larsmans That's a funny link. I've been searching for a long time, and have found lots of examples of how to get the lines, but none on how to exclude blanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
non_blank_count = 0

with open('data.txt') as infp:
    for line in infp:
       if line.strip():
          non_blank_count += 1

print 'number of non-blank lines found %d' % non_blank_count
```

UPDATE: Re-read the question, OP wants to count *non-blank* lines .. (sigh .. thanks @RanRag).
(I need a break from the computer ...)

Comment: I believe you meant `with open('data.txt') as infp:`

Comment: This doesn't work. A blank line is returned as `"\n"`, not `""`.

Comment: @mgilson I was just editing this as you made your comment -- thank!

Comment: Your code will never enter the `if` condition. So `black_count` will always be zero.

Comment: I'd use `if line.strip() = ''`

Comment: Junuxx, not infp.readlines(), as it will read all the lines at once, instead of iterating over the lines.

Comment: @Levon: I think user wants to count the number of lines in a file excluding the blank lines. He doesn't want to count the number of `blank lines`.

Comment: @Junuxx Point taken, however I think the line by line approach might be better for potentially large files since `readlines` reads the whole file into a list/memory

Comment: @Levon: Yes you really need a break ;)

Comment: yet another way: `non_blank_count = sum(1 for line in open("data.txt") if line.strip())`

Answer (score 3):

A short way to count the number of non-blank lines could be:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    num_lines = len([l for l in lines if l.strip(' \n') != ''])
```

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised to see that there isn't a clean pythonic answer yet (as of Jan 1, 2019). Many of the other answers create unnecessary lists, count in a non-pythonic way, loop over the lines of the file in a non-pythonic way, do not close the file properly, do unnecessary things, assume that the end of line character can only be `'\n'`, or have other smaller issues.

Here is my suggested solution:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    line_count = sum(1 for line in f if line.strip())
```

The question does not define what blank line is. **My definition of blank line:** `line` is a blank line if and only if `line.strip()` returns the empty string. This may or may not be your definition of blank line.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum([1 for i in open("file_name","r").readlines() if i.strip()])
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering the blank lines will only contain the new line character, it would be pretty faster to avoid calling `str.strip` which creates a new string but instead to check if the line contains only spaces using `str.isspace` and then skip it:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    non_blank_lines = sum(not line.isspace() for line in f)
```

---

Demo:

```
from io import StringIO

s = '''apple
orange
pear

hippo
donkey'''

non_blank_lines = sum(not line.isspace() for line in StringIO(s)))
# 5
```

---

You can further use `str.isspace` with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to count the number of contiguous lines/blocks in the file:

```
from itertools import groupby

no_paragraphs = sum(k for k, _ in groupby(StringIO(s), lambda x: not x.isspace()))
print(no_paragraphs)
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not blank lines Counter:

```
lines_counter = 0

with open ('test_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line != '\n':
            lines_counter += 1
```

Blocks Counter:

```
para_counter = 0
prev = '\n'

with open ('test_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line != '\n' and prev == '\n':
            para_counter += 1
        prev = line
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of Python code should solve your problem:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: 
    lines = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.strip(), f)))
```

Comment: Why the `filter` and `map`?  Couldn't you just do:  `filter(lambda x:x.strip(),f)`

Comment: I don't know that I've ever had a good reason to `import string`  :)

Comment: @mgilson: and, in my haste to edit, I completely forgot to remove that part :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would've done it:

```
f = open("file.txt")
l = [x for x in f.readlines() if x != "\n"]

print len(l)
```

`readlines()` will make a list of all the lines in the file and then you can just take those lines that have at least something in them.
Looks pretty straightforward to me!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight one! I believe

```
f = open('path','r')
count = 0
for lines in f:
    if lines.strip():
        count +=1
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

My one liner would be

```
print(sum(1 for line in open(path_to_file,'r') if line.strip()))
```