# Count input file lines to variable and repeat function that many times

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to:
store the line count of non blank lines to a variable?
then depending on the lines I need to perform action that many times.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("your_file") as file:
    nonempty_line_count = sum(1 for line in file if line != "\n")

for i in range(nonempty_line_count):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: my file has some .bin files, I have to add each .bin file in do stuff part. so how can I take each line separately and add?

Comment: line1 :CSCaa12573.SSA_AAA_SMU_1.smu.bin line2:CSCaa12567.SSA_DHCP_SMU_1.smu.bin now i have to consider each line as a variable and the do device.execute( add line1) and then till the end of file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10673560) very similar to yours where there are a variety of partial solutions posted by other users; in each case you will need to add a `for` loop as Akiino mentioned.

Comment: line1 :CSCaa12573.SSA_AAA_SMU_1.smu.bin line2:CSCaa12567.SSA_DHCP_SMU_1.smu.bin now i have to consider each line as a variable and the do device.execute( add line1) and then till the end of file

Comment: my file has some .bin files, I have to add each .bin file in do stuff part. so how can I take each line separately and add?

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your original question to include the pertinent part(s) of your current code as well as example input and expected output. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more tips.
It appears the question you originally asked is, more or less, secondary to your main goal of parsing a list of .bin files and processing some or all of them. Is this correct?